# How to assign Javascript Image object to existing Img element of JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

JSP code is written as below,

```
< img src='<%=imageURL%>' id='advt-image-top' border='0' alt=''" /><br/>
```

Where the value of imageURL is like,

http://1.2.3.4:5678/ads/avw.php?zoneid=1234567890&cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE
(Sample URL which fetches random advertisement image from Ad-Server)

Now, same JSP page contains javascript-code like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgAd = new Image();
    imgAd.src = '<%=imageURL%>';
    imgAd.onload = function(){
        if((this.width == 1 && this.height == 1)){
            document.getElementById('advt-image-top').src='img/default_top.jpg';
        }
    }
}
```

Above javascript code checks - if image returned from ad-server is of size 1x1, then it should be replaced with default-image.

Problem is, above entire code-snippet executes "imageURL" twice in order to fetch one image from ad-server : one to check whether image-returned-from-ad-server is of size 1x1 and other during  tag execution.

How can I optimize above code so that "imageURL" is executed only once?
How can I assign Image() object of javascript (after 1x1 validation is passed) to JSP's 'advt-image-top' element?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a minor adjustment to your javascript code, there is no need to create an `Image`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgAd = document.getElementById('advt-image-top');
    imgAd.onload = function(){
        if((this.width == 1 && this.height == 1)){
           imgAd.src='img/default_top.jpg';
        }
    }
}
```

However, the image might get loaded before the document ready fires and lose the onload event, so you might want to load the default url in your tag:

```
< img src='img/default_top.jpg' id='advt-image-top' border='0' alt=''" /><br/>
```

...and apply the remote url by code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgAd = document.getElementById('advt-image-top');
    imgAd.onload = function(){
        if((this.width == 1 && this.height == 1)){
           imgAd.src='img/default_top.jpg';
        }
    }
    imgAd.src='<%=imageURL%>';
}
```

**EDIT:** probably the best way is to remove the img tag altogether from the jsp and write everything with javascript. Supposing that the image is contained in an element with id "container":

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgAd = new Image();
    imgAd.onload = function(){
        if((this.width == 1 && this.height == 1)){
           imgAd.src='img/default_top.jpg';
        }
    }
    imgAd.src='<%=imageURL%>';
    imgAd.id='adv-image-top';
    imgAd.border=0;
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(imgAd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@dipanda, Thanks for your comments. Helped me solve my problem.

```
var $imgObj = $("<img/>",{src:"<%=imageURL%>"});
$imgObj.load(function(){
    var imgJS = $imgObj[0];
    if(imgJS.height == 1 && imgJS.width == 1){
        document.getElementById('advt-image-top').src='img/default_top.jpg';
    }else{
        if($("#advt-image-top")!=null && $("#advt-image-top")!=undefined){
            $("container").append($imgObj);
        }
    }
};
```